# Cost function for a set of centroids using membership probabilities

Tags: matlab, optimization, cluster-analysis

I am working on this exercise which I need to use MATLAB's fminunc function to cluster data points.

I already have the implementation for calculating the membership probabilities[image: Formula]

So I need to write an objective function which I will call the calculatemembershipProbs(data, X) function, where data contains all the datapoints and X is the variable that contains the centroids.

The question is: how do I do that? Or which formula should I use inside the objective function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how to do it.

The formula that I needed to use was: 
[image: Formula]

So I used it inside my objective function, and then I called

```
obj=@(X)ObjFunction(X, data);
[XX, fval] = fminunc(obj, X, opts);
```

And it is giving me the same results as k-means!

Answer (score 0):

Have the centroids already been provided for you?
If not how are you supposed to get the centroids have you tried using k-means?
In MatLab k-means can be used as [idx, C] = kmeans(X, k) in this case C is a vector containing all the centroids you need.

Comment: I am assigning random centroids in the beginning, and then I should use fminunc for finding the optimial centroids. My objective is to use optimization to do the clustering, and this way should give me the same result as if I use kmeans!

Comment: What is the formula you were told to use with fminunc?

Comment: Exactly, I do not know! haha. This is exactly what I am looking for. Which formula should I use inside the objective function? Because the steps are: assign random centroids, call fminunc passing this objective function which will use membership probabilities + something to find the optimal centroids and then I have a computeAssignments method which will, given the centroids and data, assign the clusters for each data point.